# Cassandra how to set default consistency - cluster level

Tags: cassandra

How to set **default consistency level** in cassandra on **cluster** level?

Cassandra documentation is mentioning it's possible:
"You can configure consistency on a cluster, data center, or individual I/O operation basis" but there's no such option in yaml file.

Answer (score 3):

With the Java Driver you can override the default CL (of ONE) when building the cluster:

```
QueryOptions qo = new QueryOptions();
qo.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);
cluster = Cluster.builder()
                 .withQueryOptions(qo)
                 .addContactPoints(CONTACT_POINTS).withPort(PORT)
                 .build();
```

The Python Driver seem to supports this also, via `ExecutionProfile`s.

In `cqlsh` use the [CONSISTENCY](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/consistency_r.html) command.

Answer (score 1):

Consistency level is set in driver level just before running a query, so there is no such option in Cassandra.yaml file.

If you intend to use a prepared statement (Java Driver example):

```
PreparedStatement prepStatement = session.prepare("select * from users");
prepStatement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ALL);
```

Our approach setting consistency level in all statements was centralizing statement creation in a utility class. With this approach we also successfully prevent memory leaks in batch statements.

[Cassandra batch statements memory leak issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6107)